# Elementor nav includes invalid tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, elementor

I have an elementor page with a nav element.

The page returns a lot of errors on the w3c validator, like this one:

> Error: Attribute migrated not allowed on element nav at this point.
>
> ```html
> <nav migration_allowed="1" migrated="0" role="navigation"
> class="elementor-nav-menu--main elementor-nav-menu__container
> elementor-nav-menu--layout-horizontal e--pointer-none">
> ```

I'm wondering how to remove these attributes, is it possible to edit the elementor pluign itself update-proof?

Or could I use a hook to edit it before rendering with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, i solved it with editing nav-menu.php on row 1276 bij adding two forward slashes before 'migration_allowed' and 'migrated'.
It's NOT update-proof, but I'm working on a custom nav-menu-widget which will solve the update problem.

```
    $this->add_render_attribute( 'main-menu', [
        //'migration_allowed' => Icons_Manager::is_migration_allowed() ? '1' : '0',
        //'migrated' => $is_migrated ? '1' : '0',
        // Accessibility
        'role' => 'navigation',
    ] );
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, i solved by installing the **Real-Time Find and Replace** by Marios Alexandrou plugin and i simply removed it from the code. So far it seems to be working just fine without it.

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glCBm.png)

Comment: I don't think the asker doesn't know about find & replace tools.